# data structure in python: best way or how to add or assign a new dictionary?

Tags: python, data-structures

I want to have this `mydict = {upperkey:{key:value,...},...}` and `keys[key1, key2, key3...]`. In the beginning I created :

```
mydict = {}
```

Then:

```
if upperkey not in mydict:
    mydict[upperkey]= dict([(keys[index+1], value)])
else:
    mydict[upperkey][keys[index+1]]= value
```

This way works fine but I find it kind of redundant and using `mydict[upperkey]= dict([(keys[index+1], value)])` just not very elegant. However, `mydict[upperkey][keys[index+1]] = value` doesn't work unless a dictionary already exists within mydict.

Anyone has a better way to do that?

Comment: What is `item`? And where do you get that value from?

Comment: it is the upper key in the first dictionary, then another dictionary is nested within item. I edited it so it should be easier to read now!

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you want the result to look like? I'm still not sure I understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`setdefault`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
mydict.setdefault(upperkey, {})[index+1] = value
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is way I'm looking for!

Comment: `defaultdict` is much simpler, really.

Comment: Wow, I'd never heard of it before: http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Comment: `defaultdict` generally is faster than using setdefault, and it is cleaner too. Well, whatever, you already know that both methods works fine so it seems you already know about everything involved here... Not sure who I'm trying to convince here.

Answer (score 4):

Are you after `defaultdict` ?

```
from collections import defaultdict
x = defaultdict(dict)
x[3][4] = 'hi'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`.setdefault(key[, default])` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)

```
subdict = mydict.setdefault(upperkey, dict([(keys[index+1], value)]))
subdict[keys[index+1]]= value
```